# Ansible Nested Loops - How to loop over a loop item?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to download keys from github and create aws key pairs. Currently I am using these tasks for that.

```
- name: download keys from github
  get_url:
    url: "https://github.com/{{ item }}.keys"
    dest: "/tmp/{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - foo
    - bar

- name: create ec2 keys 
  ec2_key: name=foo key_material="{{ item }}" state=present
  with_lines: cat /tmp/foo

- name: create ec2 keys
  ec2_key: name=bar
  with_lines: cat /tmp/bar
```

However, this is not DRY. How to achieve something like this?

```
- name: create ec2 keys 
  ec2_key: name=foo key_material="{{ line }}" state=present
  with_lines: cat /tmp/{{item}}
  with_items:
    - foo
    - bar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's `with_nested` and `with_together`, but you actually don't need them.

Try:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: https://github.com/{{ item }}.keys
        return_content: yes
      with_items:
        - user1
        - user2
        - user3
      register: github_keys
    - debug:
        msg: "user={{ item.item }} first_key={{ item.content.split('\n')[0] }}"
      with_items: "{{ github_keys.results }}"
```

Note that you may have multiple keys in github user.keys, so `ec2_key` will overwrite them in your case. I just pull first one in my example.

Update: if you want to add all keys with indexed names

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - uri:
        url: https://github.com/{{ item }}.keys
        return_content: yes
      with_items:
        - user1
        - user2
        - user3
      register: github_keys

    - set_fact:
        github_name: "{{ item.item }}"
        github_keys: "{{ lookup('indexed_items',item.content.split('\n')[:-1],wantlist=True) }}"
      with_items: "{{ github_keys.results }}"
      register: github_keys_split

    - debug:
        msg: "name={{ item[0].github_name }}_{{ item[1][0] }} key={{ item[1][1] }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ github_keys_split.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts') | list }}"
        - github_keys
```

Comment: How would you name them?

Comment: added example with multiple keys

Comment: [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-a-list-with-an-index), in combination with knowledge of _"Loops are actually a combination of things with + lookup(), so any lookup plugin can be used as a source for a loop, ‘items’ is lookup."_.